# How do I insert variables into a bytestring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I am trying to automate some AWS instances with python, and they require the `userData`—the commands run on instance startup—to be a bytestring. I want to spin up a bunch of instances with slightly different run commands. I tried this:

```
userData = base64.b64encode(
    b"""#! /bin/bash
bash runScript.sh -f {param}
""".format(param=x)
    ).decode('ascii')
```

This doesn't work, because bytestrings do not have a format method. What is the best way to insert string variables into a bytestring?

Comment: Why would you call Bash just to run a second Bash script, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with strings, then encode to bytes afterwards:

```
user_data_str = """#! /bin/bash
bash runScript.sh -f {param}
""".format(param=x)

user_data_bytes = user_data_str.encode("utf-8") # just in case there's non-ascii chars
user_data_base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(user_data_bytes)
user_data_base64_str = user_data_base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
```

If you're using Python >3.6 (You should be using Python 3.7), use `f""` strings to make your code more readable:

```
user_data_str = f"""#! /bin/bash
bash runScript.sh -f {x}
"""
```

Comment: Don't put a newline before `#!`; those need to be the first two bytes of the resulting file, not just the beginning of the first non-empty line.